# jekyll post displaying on local server, but not live

Tags: github, jekyll

i've been running [my personal site](http://ryantroyford.com/) on jekyll for years now, and i've never had this tricky of a problem.

all the projects on my site are displayed as thumbnails on the homepage, packed in there using Isotope. the viewer can then click the thumbnails to get a full explanation of the project. for my collection of photographs, i have the thumbnail image link to [another index page](https://github.com/ryantroyford/ryantroyford.com/blob/gh-pages/photo/index.html), which lists out all the posts made in the "photo" category. that photo index [still exists](http://ryantroyford.com/photo/) when the URL is manually entered, but the photo thumbnail on the homepage that leads to it has disappeared on my live site. running jekyll locally, it shows up & works fine.

this is a recent occurrence, i've been running my photo page this way for years with no problems. is it a problem with the [YML frontmatter](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ryantroyford/ryantroyford.com/gh-pages/_posts/2017-01-01-photo.md)? or the [file syntax](https://github.com/ryantroyford/ryantroyford.com/tree/gh-pages/_posts) (the "photo" link is at the bottom)? my site is hosted on github, which also might be the problem.

thanks in advance for your help. quite stuck here.

Comment: I'm not sure on where to see the issue. What's not appearing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A notable change in Github Pages : Jekyll version is now 3.0.x.

Locally, I guess, you're using Jekyll 2.x.

Main difference in our case, is that Jekyll 3.0 doesn't publish posts with a date in the future. As your `2017-01-01-photo.md` post is considered to be dated in 2017, it's not published.

In order to tel jekyll to publishe posts with future dates, you can set `future: true` in your `_config.yml`.

If you want to work locally with same dependencies than github pages, you can follow [instructions here](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-your-pages-site-locally-with-jekyll/).

Comment: this is almost certainly the problem, and would explain why it's working fine locally, but not on github. i have the "photo" post dated far in the future so Isotope always stacks it in the top left (hacky, i know). thanks so much for your help. i'll test it out when i get home today and post back.